# Seeding Relational Data in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've found several SO posts on this but can't identify what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to seed two tables with an item each. The second item contains a lookup to the first. I can seed the parent with no issue, but cannot figure out the correct syntax to seed the child.

Here is the code I use to seed the parent

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasData(new Group
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Any",
            IsDeleted = false
        });
```

And here is the code to seed the child - this fails:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ShiftTypeDb>().HasData(new 
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Any",
            GroupId = 1,

            IsDeleted = false
        });
```

Following the advice from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) I've used an anonymous object instead of the class itself. I've also tried using the navigation property and both the foreign key and the nav prop at the same time. The Group with id=1 is definitely in the db already so it isn't a question of the parent item not existing.

The error message I get is:

> Insert or update on table "shifttypes" violates foreign key constraint "fk_shifttypes_groups_groupid"

And the SQL generated for the seed is

```
INSERT INTO shifttypes (id, groupid, isdeleted, name)
VALUES (1, 0, FALSE, 'Any');
```

It is clearly inserting a '0' as the GroupId, despite it being hardcoded as '1' in the seed; I cannot figure out why this is the case. Below is the code for the two entities that represent these two tables:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
    }

    public Group(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ShiftTypeDb
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }

    public ShiftTypeDb()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was tested in Visual Studio and worked properly. After fixing all bugs you have to delete existing db and migration and create the new one using Add-Migration InitialCreate option.

You have one-to-one relation instead of one-to-many. To fix the bug add ShiftTypeDb collection to the Group class:

```
    public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShiftTypeDb> ShifTypeDbs { get; set; }

   ...other properties
}
```

ans use ShiftTypeDb instead of anonymous type. Anonymous types are used only if your class have  shadow properties. And be sure that group is ahead of TypeDB

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ShiftTypeDb>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasOne(d => d.Group)
                        .WithMany(p => p.ShiftTypeDbs)
                        .HasForeignKey("GroupId");
                });
 

modelBuilder.Entity<ShiftTypeDb>().HasData(new ShiftTypeDb 
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Any",
            GroupId = 1,
            IsDeleted = false
        })
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, I've done the above (added ICollection<ShiftTypeDb> ShiftTypes to the Group entity, FluentAPI code to conifgure the relationship and changed the annonymous object to the object initialiser for ShiftTypeDb) but I get the same error message.

Comment: You have to migrate your db again

Comment: Thanks Sergey, turns out the issue was that I had to remove the previous migrations for the new changes to work. I was able to get it to work without adding the ICollection<ShiftTypeDb> to the Group collection in the end.

Comment: I am sorry but you just haven't tested it properly. It's a bug. You will not be able to add another ShiftTypeDb record without adding the ICollection<ShiftTypeDb>.

Comment: From my perspective @Serge 's comments are weird. It is theoretically possible to add a one-to-many relationship by using only the FK, without the need for an actual navigation field (the Collection of Serge's recommendation). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#without-navigation-property